# Pulling list data from caret into a data frame

Tags: r, r-caret

I was curious about the ecosystem of machine learning algorithms available in the `caret` package, but quickly found myself up against a problem of converting lists to data frames.

I was looking to build a dataset that consisted of the `caret` method name, its label, associated libraries, its type (classification, regression), and tags.

My first step was to do:

```
library(caret)
carets <- getModelInfo()
```

This puts all of the `caret` model info into a single gigantic named list. I can get the sub-elements of the list by doing:

```
attach(carets)
ada$label
ada$library
ada$type
ada$tags
```

Is there a way to extract that info from the entirety of the list? I've tried:

```
library(data.table)
carets.df <- data.frame(unlist(carets))
carets.df2 <- rbindlist(carets, fill=TRUE)
carets.df3 <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, carets)
carets.df4 <- lapply(carets, function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
```

to no avail. I feel like I'm close but I'm not super familiar with lists and extracting named elements programmatically...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it seems like you are trying to stick non-tabular data into a `data.frame`, which holds tabular data.

Comment: What's the benefit of conversion to a data frame? The `library` and `tags` variables will be vectors, so you'll have to either store them as delimited text or split them across rows, resulting in a lot of duplication. Might be better to figure out how to work with the list.

Comment: There isn't really any benefit, but it just worked out better from a readability standpoint for what I was looking for. My answer has details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really stems from my ignorance of how finding specific list elements works, but in this case the hacky way below got what I was after:

```
carets <- getModelInfo()

carets.names <- names(carets)

carets.library <- 0
carets.label <- 0
carets.type <- 0
carets.tags <- 0

for(i in 1:length(carets.names)){
  carets.library <- c(carets.library, toString(carets[[i]][["library"]]))
  carets.label <- c(carets.label, carets[[i]][["label"]])
  carets.type <- c(carets.type, toString(carets[[i]][["type"]]))
  carets.tags <- c(carets.tags, toString(carets[[i]][["tags"]]))
}

carets.df <- data.frame(carets.names, carets.library[2:228], carets.label[2:228], carets.type[2:228], carets.tags[2:228])
```